# Google Go Win: can't find import "http"

Tags: windows, http, go

I downloaded Go for Windows (go.weekly.2012-01-27.windows-amd64.tar.gz), set the environment variables

```
GOOS=windows
GOROOT=c:\go
GOBIN=c:\go\bin
GOARCH=386
```

and was able to create a HelloWorld.exe. Now I've tried a very simple example that imports "http", but it doesn't find it. Do I need goinstall or add sth. to the PATH?

Comment: Don't use the old version, otherwise you will waste time.  Just download the newest weekly version http://code.google.com/p/go/downloads/list will similar to Go v1.0

Answer (score 32, accepted):

import "[net/http](http://weekly.golang.org/pkg/net/http/)" // was "http" in r60 IIRC

Comment: Ah! Thanks! Seems they haven't updated golang.org/pkg/http/, but you can look for it in the packages-folder (here: pkg\windows_amd64).

Comment: FYI, documentation at `golang.org` reflects r60. Weekly releases are documented at `weekly.golang.org` and tip at `tip.golang.org`.